# SPS 2013 homepage, footer visible wen viewed at 80% mode

Tags: sharepoint-server, footer

SPS 2013 homepage, footer visible wen viewed at 80%  mode.
In 100% for whatever reason the footer doesn't appear in the screen. Seems the screen doesn't goes till the bottom of the page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which browser are you using? try in another PC with different Screen size Or different  resolution, different browser (IE is compatible with SP)

Comment: @amitKoyani, I`ve tested from 3 desktop on Chrome as well as IE 10 / 11, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

CSS code for Footer part of Global CSS file.
Add !important against all CSS code specific to Footer.
Eventually that worked and did the job.
Seems some other CSS on the Homepage was causing the Footer to appear in 100% view.